# C++ priority queue does not sort

Tags: c++, priority-queue

I tried to implement a priority queue in C++ with a custom Class and Compare struct, but whenever I push a new element the queue doesn´t sort itself.

In Header:

```
private:
    std::priority_queue<Node*, std::vector<Node*>, NodeCompare> queue;
```

Struct:

```
struct NodeCompare
{
    bool operator()(Node* n1, Node* n2) 
    {
        int val1 = n1->getValue();
        int val2 = n2->getValue();
        return val1 < val2;
    }
};
```

In Class:

```
Node* node = new Node(nrInTree, value);
queue.push_back(node);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't sort itself"? Any example?

Comment: Also, the `operator ()` should be `const`.

Comment: I understood that when I push an element, the queue automatically orders itself according to the CompareStruct.
So in my Case if I push three Nodes with Values 5,9,6 (in that order) the queue is arranges itself to 5,6,9. 
Is that correct or do I just get the concept wrong?

Comment: I'd like to see a example as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Works [here](https://ideone.com/6K1SJf).

Comment: `std::priority_queue` is a [max heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap). The elements in the underlying container are not in sorted order.

Comment: There is no `push_back` on a `priority_queue`...

Comment: Ok, thanks guys. I just figured that the queue at least always holds the smallest element on top, even though the rest of the queue might not be in order. But for my cause thats enough.
Sry for your trouble. I´m new here. Next time I post a more organized code ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is correct. But I think you have a misunderstanding here.
Because priority_queue is implemented using data structure heap.
As we know, heap is not sorted. It only has the property that the maximum element
is at the front. Every time, you insert an element into a heap, heap will use O(lgN)
time to push the maximum into the front.
And every time you pop an element, the largest element will be obtained.
But heap is not sorted at all.